# Remove "Open link in a new window/tab" checkbox in Post link visual editor

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site for a group of authors and have set it up to universally display internal links in the same tab while displaying external links in a new tab.

Unfortunately, the "Open link in a new window/tab" checkbox that appears in the link pop-up in the visual editor is causing them to freak out.

Does anyone know where this pop-up window is located and the best way I can filter this to remove that line and checkbox altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function to your functions.php file. It will add a style to the admin area that hides the "link target" div:

```
function hide_link_target() {
  echo '<style>
    .link-target {display:none;}
  </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_link_target');
```